# Extra blank pages in RDLC PDF report

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an RDLC report in asp.net, After clicking on PDF icon PDF generated but unfortunately one after the other blank page is taken. How to remove this blank pages ?
I also set `ConsumeContainerWhitespace=true` but it still not working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to determine from that image alone but there are some common issues that you can test for.

1. Page Width (Horizontal Overflow)
2. Page Height (Vertical Overflow)
3. Duplicate Page Breaks
4. Overlapping Containers

### Page Width (Horizontal Overflow)

The first issue is page width. Check that the width of the container that holds your tablix is less than the printable page width, minus the margins. Todo this, we first need to know the current margins. One way to do this is to right click the grey canvas outside of the report in the designer and select the `Report Properties` from the context menu:
[image]

You can see that this report has A4 page size, 21cm width and left and right margins of 1cm:
[image]

You could also have left clicked the same grey canvas area and pressed `F4` to view the Properties Grid for the Report. You will find both `PageSize` and `Margins` Properties:

[image]

Now we can go back to the report and right click any element in the report, goto the `Select` menu and click on the `body` container:
[image: find the root body container]

If the *Properties* explorer is open you will see the properties for the body, otherwise press `F4` to open the properties explorer.

In the `Size` property you will see the `Width`:
[image]

- We need the `Body` width, in this case `~17.13cm` to be less than the page width (21cm) minus the margins (2cm):

  ```
  21 - 2 = 19
  17.13 < 19   [true]
  ```

  so this particular report will not overflow horizontally!

### Page Height (Vertical Overflow)

Similar to the page height, if your content exceeds the vertical height of the page, minus the margins, then a new page will be added. If your content gets close to the bottom edge of the page, you may not need to add deliberate page breaks at all.

To detect this, I often set the background colour of containers that might be overflowing, then in the print preview or PDF export output you will be able to identify containers that span multiple pages that you were not expecting to.

### Duplicate Page Breaks

It is pretty easy to set multiple page breaks that will fall at the same point. Check that your tablix and Row Groups do not both have page breaks set:

[image]

[image]

Using the temporary background colour hack here will also help, but set different colours for different containers or groups to distinguish between them.

### Overlapping Containers

If the previous solutions do not help, the last common issue with export to PDF is that containers cannot overlap in the same *extended horizontal plane*.

This is hard to explain, but in the preview and html views, the following alignment for textboxes or rectangles will work
[image]

But if the layout was like this:
[image]

It can end up rendering like this if the content in the right box is allowed to grow (`Can Grow = true`) and the content makes it expand:
[image]

- I don't think this is an issue in this case, but can't easily tell. Use the background colour hack again to help identify these issues.